# Vivid - broken package using upstart on a systemd install

Tags: package-management, upstart, systemd, dnscrypt-proxy

I tried to get dnscrypt-proxy working from this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt

EDIT: this PPA is outdated, and the correct one to use is
https://launchpad.net/~xuzhen666/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt

After installing, it complains about upstart not being available.

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get -f install
Setting up dnscrypt-proxy (1.6.0-3pmo1~vivid) ...
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'dnscrypt-proxy' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `dnscrypt-proxy'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `dnscrypt-proxy'
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
Failed to restart dnscrypt-proxy.service: Unit dnscrypt-proxy.service failed to load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnscrypt-proxy, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package dnscrypt-proxy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dnscrypt-proxy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'd rather not switch back to upstart if not needed. Do I have to wait on the package maintainer to update the package for systemd?

I cannot remove the package with dpkg or apt-get because it tries to shut down the service and fails with similar errors.

```
Removing dnscrypt-proxy (1.6.0-3pmo1~vivid) ...
Failed to stop dnscrypt-proxy.service: Unit dnscrypt-proxy.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnscrypt-proxy, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package dnscrypt-proxy (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
...
```

Running the command shown in the error log above:

```
~ systemctl status dnscrypt-proxy.service
dnscrypt-proxy.service - DNSCrypt proxy
Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
Active: inactive (dead)
 Docs: man:dnscrypt-proxy(8)
systemd[1]: dnscrypt-proxy.service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.
```

Comment: In this case you should ask the developer.

Comment: How can I remove it in the mean time?

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get purge dnscrypt-proxy`

Comment: And if `ppa-purge` is installed: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:xuzhen666/dnscrypt`

Comment: The apt-get purge results in the same type of error, see second from last error above

Comment: Check the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/dnscrypt-proxy.prerm`, the pre-removal script and search for the command to stop the service, anything like `service … stop`. Comment the lines out and try it again. I will check this later at home to give a better explanation.

Comment: I commented out every line in that file and was able to purge the package. Thanks for the help! I've contacted the package maintainer to ask about systemd support

Comment: Converted my comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug, you should ask the developer. In the meantime remove the package.

1. Check the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/dnscrypt-proxy.prerm`, the pre-removal script and search for the command to stop the service, anything like `service … stop`. Comment the lines out and try it again. I will check this later at home to give a better explanation.
2. `sudo apt-get purge dnscrypt-proxy`

Comment: Don't thank me! ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: :D I like the comment! +1  VTC

Comment: @Fabby Nice comment, isn't it? Why VTC?

Answer (score -2):

You could try this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-efi-amd64_ linux-efi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install linux-efi
```

and then this:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /com/upstart
sudo nano /com/upstart/upstart
```

and then write this:

```
[default]
plymouth-upstart-bridge=default
```

and it might work fine this way.